# AWS java SDK manually set signature version

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to access a blob store service which is on top of AWS S3. It supports AWS SDK and it's signature version 2.

I'm using [code here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html) to access the this service.

**Is it possible to manually set the signature version of the request made by AWS SDK ?**

According to [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html)

> AWS currently supports two signature versions: signature version 2 and signature version 4, which are covered in this section. Most services support version 4, and if a service supports version 4, we strongly recommend that you use that version.

I'm unable to find how to set the signature version to 2 or 4 manually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the S3 Developer Guide - [Specifying Signature Version in Request Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html#specify-signature-version):

> **Java SDK**
>
> Add the following in your code.
>
> `System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");`
>
> Or, on the command line, specify the following.
>
> `-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4`

It looks like v2 was the default in the AWS SDK previously, but v4 is now the default starting in [SDK v1.11.0 (May, 2016)](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/9979983567247718).

Comment: Anyone using Spark 2.4.4 with aws-java-sdk 1.7.4, hadoop-aws 2.7.5 and getting 400 error even after setting region correctly, then this is the solution which worked for me
Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2):

as of

aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163

> **SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY is deprecated.**

I used the below code to call using signature_version='s3'

```
private static ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();

static {
    config.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
    config.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");
}
private static AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withClientConfiguration(config)
    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("endpoint", null))
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_Key")))
    .build();
```