# Error while read object in when use Rest-easy web service

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to read object which [uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817540/error-while-decrypting-file-using-kms-key-in-amazon-s3) using `Server side encryption` with `AWS KMS` key encryption

adding the property

```
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest genreq = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(BUCKET_NAME, Keyname, HttpMethod.GET);
    URL puturl = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(genreq);
```

This code is working when upload and Read from `AWS S3` both perform same time but when i am trying it with connection `AWSCredentials` and `AmazonS3` First deploy in server using `restEasy` web service it's not working and still get the same below error

> code : InvalidArgumentRequests
>
> message : specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version

Is there any suggestions? Please help.