# Bad request when using s3a protocol on V4 s3 buckets

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to download files from a s3 bucket on the Frankfurt region.

Originally encountered this problem in spark 2.2.1 with hadoop 2.7.5.

I got  this message:

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: F6EB301E99C9BC7A, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID:

setting

```
       sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")
```

Didn't change a thing.

running  `./hadoop-2.7.5/bin/hadoop fs -ls s3a://frankfurt-bucket-name`
returns the exact same error.

this is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
  <value>s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

How do can I make hadoop use V4 signature?

Comment: with hadoop-3.0.1 and aws-sdk 1.11.999 it works out of the box with no need to configure the s3a endpoint

Comment: That 1.10. version of the AWS SDK needs to be told system property to switch to v4 auth..afraid I don't know the name, so you'll be left googling for it yourself. The good news: it can be done!

Comment: I tried setting `fs.s3a.signing-algorithm` to `V4` on aws-hadoop 2.7.5 and aws sdk 1.7.4 but it didn’t help ‍♀️

Comment: That's an S3A option which was only supported in Hadoop 2.8+. Like I warned, you are going to have to find the JVM system property which switches it to use v4 signing. There is one, I don't remember the value, I'm afraid

Comment: now I get it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154484/aws-java-sdk-manually-set-signature-version

Comment: that's the one.

Comment: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.0.1/ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

upgrading hadoop and spark versions solved the problem.