# Read Files from S3 bucket to Spark Dataframe using Scala in Datastax Spark Submit giving AWS Error Message: Bad Request

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to read CSV files which are on s3 bucket which is located in Mumbai Region.I'm trying to read the files using datastax dse spark-submit.

I tried changing hadoop-aws version to various other versions. Currently, hadoop-aws version is 2.7.3

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com")

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", accessKeyId)

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretAccessKey)

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")

val df = spark.read.csv("s3a://bucket_path/csv_name.csv")
```

Upon Executing, Following is the error which I'm getting,

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400,
>   AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 8C7D34A38E359FCE, AWS Error
>   Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request    at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1031)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:994)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:350)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:350)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:533)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:412)

Comment: check, your access key and secret access are valid or not

Comment: Yes they are valid keys. This code works perfectly for US East Bucket

Comment: You probably wan to run your s3 cleint as debug or you can search for a long time . 
Also  beware you can either track your request using your request ID or even contact support to get what's  wrong with that specific  request ID especially if your have enabled server logging

Comment: Or check the resource you are accessing. Is it available in that region or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your signature V4 option is not applied. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154484/aws-java-sdk-manually-set-signature-version)

Add the java option when you run the spark-submit or spark-shell.

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
```

Or, set the system property such as:

```
System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true");
```

Comment: Ran the app using the mentioned parameters. Still giving the same error.

Comment: I have modified a bit, please check it. I am pretty sure your code is not working with V4 and the problem is how to implement that. At least you know what you have to do.

Comment: OP - has already set this property. It is unnecessary to set it again.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

The code worked after adding

System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true")

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the help. I figured out from the answer of Lamanus that signature V4 option was not applied even after adding it in

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
```

So I added the following line and now the code works perfectly fine.

```
import com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration

System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true")
```

Comment: Hii, I cant seem to find how to set the same thing in pyspark. Any idea?

Comment: @Chinmay R Thanks man it did help me , using scala-spark in intellij