# How to use Temporary credentials from AssumeRole in Spark configuration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm currently facing a issue where I'm unable to create a Spark session (through PySpark) that uses temporary credentials (from a assumed role in a different AWS account).

The idea is to assume a role in Account B, get temporary credentials and create the spark session in Account A, so that Account A is allowed to interact with Account B through the Spark Session.

I've almost tried every possible configuration available in my spark session. Is there anyone that has some reference material to create a spark session using temporary credentials?

```py
role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::account-b:role/example-role"
duration_seconds = 60*15 # durations of the session in seconds

# obtain the temporary credentials
credentials = boto3.client("sts").assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName=role_session_name#,
#    DurationSeconds=duration_seconds
)['Credentials']

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .appName("test") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/usr/local/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.10.0.jar,/usr/local/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar")\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", credentials['AccessKeyId']) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", credentials['SecretAccessKey']) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

The above seems to not work, it does not implicitly use the credentials I pass to the spark session. It uses the actual underlying execution role of the process.

Looking at the documentation there's also some notes on 'short living credentials' not being supported. So I wonder how others are able to create a spark session with temporary credentials?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark issues with Temporary AWS tokens for authentication with s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110262/pyspark-issues-with-temporary-aws-tokens-for-authentication-with-s3)

Answer (score -1):

1. update hadoop aws and compatible binaries (including aws sdk) to one written in the last eight years.
2. which will then include the [temporary credential support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12537)